# What byte representation does Java Sound API use audio streams?

Tags: python, java

I tried to read a **16-bit** encoded wav file using Java Sound API and send the file to a Python script via an HTTP request, but the Python script could not properly read the file.

After some investigation, it seems that the data in Java is represented by pairs of integers (m, n), and that the corresponding values in Python have the following form:

```
m + n * 2**8 if m >= 0

m + (n + 1) * 2**8 else
```

A few examples:

(-94,1) -> 418

(-31,-6) -> -1311

What is this encoding? Is there an efficient way to convert it to what is needed in Python?

Comment: Please double check that what you are asking about is the XOR operator `^`. I somehow suspect that you mean something else.

Comment: Please also check the `+1`, it is slightly less unlikely than the `^`, but it is a little off the most likely explanation I can think of.

Comment: Pretty sure they mean exponentiation.

Comment: @Yunnosch about "^", you're absolutely right, I'm just struggling to use the markdown for exponents. Abouth the "+1", I could be wrong but let me add a few examples.

Comment: Are sure that this isn't just a signed or unsigned 16 bit number represented as 2 Java bytes?  How are you reading the wav file?  How are you extracting the `m` and `n` values?

Comment: @StephenC I don't know, it could well be, that's why I'm asking! I'm following this example: https://www.codejava.net/coding/how-to-play-back-audio-in-java-with-examples

Comment: @nayriz how did you come to the conclusion that "the corresponding values in Python have the following form"? How are you reading these values? It's likely just a misinterpretation of the raw bytes as a specific numeric format.

Comment: @Grismar , good question. I opened the same file using scipy.io.wavfile and compared the values.

Comment: @Yunnosch my formula was wrong, it seems that the new one is correct.

Comment: @StephenC is there an easy way to convert a 2 Java bytes to a 16-bit in either Java or Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get Ture Pålsson's code to work, so I ended doing

```
P = M + ( N + np.floor((N - np.sign(N)*1)/2) )*256
```

in Python, where M, N and P are all Numpy arrays.

(More than happy to accept another answer if someone comes up with something more efficient/elegant and/or a detailed description of what's going on with Java Sound API.)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like bog-standard little-endian two's-complement. Take your sample numbers:

```
import struct
struct.pack('<hh', 418, -1311).hex()
# Yields a201e1fa
```

Now A2, when interpreted as an 8-bit signed two's complement number (Java likes its bytes signed, for some reason) is -94. 01 is 1, obviously, and e1, fa are -31 and -6, respectively. So, if you have read your data as a byte array, you can decode it to integers using `struct.unpack('<4711h', the_array)`, where 4711 is the length of the array.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean that the Java Sound API is using bog-standard little-endian two's-complement, and you then gave the Python code to turn it into a regular PCM 16-bit byte array?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Java Sound API, so I cannot comment on that, but it seems likely that what you have there *is* a regular PCM 16-bit array; you're just looking at it the wrong way.